# Datatables - Border style not applied to table cell that is empty

Tags: css, datatable, datatables

I am having a styling issue with datatables. The browsers I am supporting are IE 6 through to 10.

Whevever I have empty rows in a td content the border of the cell goes funny and distorts. See image below.
[image]

I've had a look at the difference in styles between an empty table cell and it looks like if there is an empty cell datatables does not include the border properties for the cell. See below....

**HTML Style for a row without empty cells is as follows...**
[image]

**Style for a row without empty cells is as follows...**
[image]

**HTML for a row with an empty cells is as follows...**
[image]

**Style for a row with an empty cells is as follows...**
[image]

Can someone help me with how I might be able to fix this problem?

Is it because the td tags are empty tags when there is no content? Does css get applied differently for empty tags? I didn't think so...

I am using data tables 1.9.4.

thanks

Comment: Please show your exact CSS, and preferable a jsfiddle the reproduces the problem. Obviously you have some customised CSS that are overruling the default dataTables CSS - you must include that.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your reply. I'll update with full css soon. Id like to challenge you on your response. If my css was overriding the data tables css then how is the styling working for those rows that have content? I.e. I don't think it is possible to override a style for an empty td unless you code that in javascript which I have not. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a key thing that I can now clarify is that the problem is specific to ie6 and also when running in compatibility mode in ie10 and below. When I switched compatibility mode off in ie10 i did not have the problem.

When looking into it more there is a datatables bug logged for this problem.
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-1236

As a work around to the issue i used javascript to do the following...

```
   $('#search-results-table')
   .on('processing.dt',function( e, settings, processing ){
       if (processing){
               ....

       }else {
               ....
               $('#search-results-table td:empty').html('&nbsp;');
       }
       } )
```

i.e. after processing add &nbsp for empty cells. It fixed the problem. Special thanks to davidkonrad for helping me resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

As a response to the friendly *challenge* in the comments : You can indeed override styling for an empty `<td>` without using javascript. Consider this example, targeting dataTables 1.9.4 (demo below)

```css
table.dataTable td {
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
table.dataTable {
    border-collapse: separate;
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/f5Lvd4xa/**

[image]

Open the fiddle, try to comment out the last CSS class and update. Without seeing the content of your custom CSS - `custom-myer.css` and `styles.jsp` - I cannot know for *sure* what exactly is going on in your particular case, but the above pretty much looks like the experience you have.

Comment: thanks. I didn't know that this could be done using a pre css solution. A very good learning for me.